# How do we write gremlin update/modify query in node.js?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

How do we write gremlin update/modify query in node.js  ?

I want to update particular field and save the same and do not modify other fields which are not edited.

I have a table called "org" and it has some properties like name, id, label.
How can we modify particular property or all the properties depends on the put body request ? using gremlin query

Comment: I have a table called "org" and it has some properties like name, id, label.                         
How can we modify particular property or all the properties depends on the put body request ? using gremlin query

Answer (score 0):

Any property can be updated as follows (assuming it is a single value and not a set)

```
g.V('some-id').
  property(Cardinality.single,'my-property',new-value).
  iterate()
```

UPDATED: If you need to update the contents of multiple properties you can just chain the `property` steps together.

```
g.V('some-id').
  property(Cardinality.single,'p1',new-value).
  property(Cardinality.single,'p2',new-value).  
  property(Cardinality.single,'p3',new-value).  
  property(Cardinality.single,'p4',new-value).iterate()
```

UPDATED again

If you only want to set a property value if the property already exists you can check for its existence using a 'has' step as shown below.

```
g.V('some-id').
  has('p1').
  property(Cardinality.single,'p1',new-value)
```

If you want to do this for more than one property you can use `optional` steps as one way to do multiple of these checks.

```
g.V('some-id').
  optional(has('p1').
    property(Cardinality.single,'p1',new-value)).
  optional(has('p2').
    property(Cardinality.single,'p2',new-value)).
```

Some additional information can be found at [1] and [2]

[1] http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#addnodes

[2] https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addproperty-step

Comment: this is working for single property update, how can we update multiple properties in a vertices?

Comment: I added another example to the answer and provided a couple of links to further examples.

Comment: is there way to update property dynamically ? I mean when the field is not present it should not update that field ?

Comment: I added some additional examples.  I suggest opening a new question  if you have additional follow up questions so this does not become a super long thread.

Comment: also if the answer is OK for the current questions it would be nice if you could accept it so that others can see this one has an answer. Many thanks